# correct way to check string array is not null

Tags: c#

I have a string array and it always gives string array length > 0. what is the correct way to check that the string array is not null.

```
string[] mystr = new string[0];
...
...
if (..) {
    mystr = string[] oldstrArray.Clone();
    }
...
...

if (mystr[0].Length != 0) {
//Always enters this loop even if mystr is not assigned in the above if condition
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with a programming language.

Comment: String can contain no character or be null.  These are two different conditions.  to test for both use string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @jdweng: OP doesn't want to check if a `string` is null or empty but a `String[]`.

Comment: So he tests for != IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 4):

Try this code snippet:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] mystr = null;
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(mystr))
    {
         //Do your thing
    }            
}

static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string[] strarray)
{
    return strarray== null || strarray.Length == 0;
}
```

Or this one (Extension Method)

```
class MyAwesomeProgram
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] mystr = null;
        if (mystr.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            //Do what you want
        }
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string[] strarray)
    {
        return strarray == null || strarray.Length == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check `strarray < 1` in the "normal function" but changed the extension to `strarray == 0`?

Comment: I know that it was an edit. 'cause I expandend your answer with the extension method. That's why I asked you. I wanted to know why my solution was corrected but not your own ^^ btw. i edited your edit :D ('cause I had to change at least 6 chars, i changed a comment in the code)

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for the length of the *first string* in the array, not the array itself. You want to check for `mystr.Length` instead of `mystr[0].Length`.

Also, pay attention to the code you're posting - it should compile (LINQPad is very useful for this). Yours has syntax errors, which may hinder people trying to help you.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] mystr = new string[] { "", null, "", "", null };

//Check if the array itself is null which is what your question is truly asking
if (mystr == null) 
    Console.WriteLine("Array is null");

//Check to see if the array itself is empty/zero-length
if (mystr != null && mystr.Length == 0) 
    Console.WriteLine("Array contains no elements");

//Check if all elements are null or empty
if (mystr != null && mystr.All(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))) 
    Console.WriteLine("All elements are either null or empty");
```

Comment: to complete your answer you could add the case mystr.Any :). Which is what your writeline in the last case suggests. Your comment on the last case is correct.

Comment: @Uwe My original answer actually did use `.Any()`, but I decided it was better off using `.All()`, but I forgot to change the `.WriteLine()` =\

Answer (score 0):

> if (mystr[0].Length != 0)

It will give you the length of first member of the array. Null check is simple

if(mystr == null)

Length property gives you the size of the array. Length can be used to check empty array